# Force Blazor Web App to Login on EVERY APP START (do not save previous session login info)

Tags: c#, authentication, session, blazor

I've got a decent Blazor Web App going with authentication, logins, etc working well from the Demo.

The only thing I do not like is that after I close the browser [x] then restart the project again from visual studio, it shows me as *Still Logged in*.

I want the default behavior to ignore the login status on application start and **ALWAYS force any user to login**--even if they were just logged in 30 seconds ago but happened to accidentally close their browser.

-- This is the code in my Login.Razor page. I had presumed the bit where it says // Clear the existing external cookie...// would do the trick.

```
 [CascadingParameter]
 public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

 [SupplyParameterFromForm]
 public InputModel Input { get; set; } = default!;

 [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
 public string ReturnUrl { get; set; } = "";

 public class InputModel
 {
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; } = false;
 }

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    Input ??= new();
    ReturnUrl ??= "/";

    if (HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))
    {
       // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
       await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    }
 }

 public async Task LoginUser()
 {
    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
       SharedAppData.LoggedInThisSession = true;
       Logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");            
     }
     RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
     }
      if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
      {
          RedirectManager.RedirectTo(
              "/Account/LoginWith2fa",
              new() { ["ReturnUrl"] = ReturnUrl, ["RememberMe"] = Input.RememberMe });
      }
      if (result.IsLockedOut)
      {
          Logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
          RedirectManager.RedirectTo("/Account/Lockout");
      }
      else
      {
          errorMessage = "Error: Invalid login attempt.";
      }
  }
```

On the top of my other pages such as the *Home (index)*, I use the **@attribute [Authorize]** such that there's an auto redirect back to login when the user isn't logged in. That works fine.

Problem is, when I restart the application, I'm already logged in and the Home page shows.

Comment: You've not shown how you're currently persisting a user's identity - that might be helpful.